# how to put recaptcha and submit in one line contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, css, layout, contact-form-7

How to add these elements in one line:

```
[recaptcha] [submit "Send"]
```

So recaptcha will be on the left and submit button on the right
WordPress wraps each shortcode with div.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a CSS -related question. You may wish to add CSS as your tag, or add some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the fields class names in Contact Form 7:

```
<div class="clearfix">[recaptcha id:recaptchaform]<p class="cf7submitbtn">[submit "Send"]</p></div>
```

Then set your CSS to be:

```
.recaptchaform {float:left}
.cf7submitbtn {float:right}
```